# Is it possible to use Mysql Full-text seach if CKEDITOR stores texts on database in HTML format?

Tags: ckeditor

All is in the title :

I have to use a Wysywig editor, maybe Ckeditor, for self-made forum.
I believe Ckeditor saves texts in HTML format in database.
There is probably a problem if we want use Mysql Full-text seach, no ?
Because of tags, and html entities.

The other question : the best parctice with Wysiwig editor : save messages in HTML ou Plain Text ?

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will not user fullindexes search but tags in another column.